# Roboelectric test case failure with RxJava "java.lang.AssertionError: Values at position 0 differ; expected"

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java2, robolectric

My test case got a failure when testing my room database. This is the class that acts as an intermediate between room database and my repository class ...

```
class Cache @Inject constructor(var newsDb:NewsDb  ,var newsDbMapper: NewsDbMApperImpl) : DataStore {
    override fun getNews(): Observable<List<News>> {
       return newsDb.newsDao().getNews().toObservable().map {
            it.map {
                newsEntity ->
                newsDbMapper.mapEntityToNews(newsEntity)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getNewsByTitle(title:String) :Observable<News> {
       return newsDb.newsDao().getNewsByTitle(title).map {t ->
            newsDbMapper.mapEntityToNews(t)
        }
    }

    fun saveNews(list:List<News>):Completable{
        return    Completable.defer{
            var listNews = list.map {
                newsDbMapper.mapNewsToEntity(it)
            }
            newsDb.newsDao().insertNews(listNews)
            Completable.complete()
        }
    }
}
```

The Test case for this class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class CacheTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var newsDB: NewsDb
    private lateinit var newsDbMapper: NewsDbMApperImpl
    private lateinit var cache: Cache

    @Before
    fun initDatabase() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        newsDB = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, NewsDb::class.java)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
        newsDbMapper = NewsDbMApperImpl()
        cache = Cache(newsDB, newsDbMapper)
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDatabase() {
        newsDB.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun insertNewsSavesData() {
        val newsList = listOf(ProjectDataFactory.makeNews())
        val testObserver = cache.saveNews(newsList).test()
        testObserver.assertComplete()
    }

    @Test
    fun getNewsReturnsData() {
        val newsList = arrayListOf(ProjectDataFactory.makeNews())
        cache.saveNews(newsList).test()
        val testObserver = cache.getNews().test()
        testObserver.await(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        testObserver.assertValue(newsList)
    }

    @Test
    fun getNewsByTitleReturnsCorrectData() {
        val news = ProjectDataFactory.makeNews()
        val title = news.title
        val newsList = listOf(news)
        cache.saveNews(newsList).test()
        val testObserver = cache.getNewsByTitle(title).test()
        testObserver.assertValue(news)
    }


}
```

But I am getting an error alike:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: [com.example.newreaderapplication.datastore.model.News@6017ad4a] (class: ArrayList) but was: [com.example.newreaderapplication.datastore.model.News@27e113e9] (class: ArrayList) (latch = 1, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 0, timeout!)
Expected :[com.example.newreaderapplication.datastore.model.News@6017ad4a] (class: ArrayList) 
Actual   :[com.example.newreaderapplication.datastore.model.News@27e113e9] (class: ArrayList) (latch = 1, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 0, timeout!)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please scroll through the entire code block.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. I've edited the question and made it 2 code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two different List objects so equals() return false when trying to compare them. Even if your content is identical. Try to compare size of list and list content item by item

Comment: `val news = ProjectDataFactory.makeNews()
        val title = news.title
        val newsList = listOf(news)
        cache.saveNews(newsList).test()
        val testObserver = cache.getNewsByTitle(title).test()
        testObserver.assertValue{value-> value.size()==news.size()}
.assertValue{value-> value[0]==news[0]}`
e.t.c